# Can I turn my old iPhone into a stationary iOS hub?

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, lightning

I want to turn my old iPhone Xr into a permanent iOS hub on the wall in my bathroom. I have an HomePod mini already but I feel that I also need a screen there to check the weather, reminders and control my HomePod mini to turn on podcasts and music.

Two questions:

1. Can I keep my iPhone constantly charging in the bathroom without risk? (I don’t care if the battery goes bad)
2. If it’s not safe to keep it charging 100% of the time, is it possible to remove a battery and power an iPhone straight from the cable?

If both answers are negative I believe the only option is to unplug the cable regularly, once a month or so just to refresh the battery lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had several iPads set up as library kiosks for years in locking stands which are permanently connected to power and they suffered no damage. IIRC, once the battery is charged up, iOS will not continue to pass current to the battery, leading to over-charging.

Apple is also very proactive when it comes to battery health, depending on hardware and version of iOS.

Seeing that you plan to place the iPhone in a bathroom, I’d be more concerned about excess humidity levels from showers, etc, and from splashing, depending on the location.